# Batch file to join and re-format lines

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that will process a file with records like this:

```
c:\SSSM\logs\CAP61.K10TEST.LOAD.log:  299 Rows successfully loaded.
c:\SSSM\logs\CAP61.K10TEST.LOAD.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
c:\SSSM\logs\CAP63.K10TEST.LOAD.log:  232 Rows successfully loaded.
c:\SSSM\logs\CAP63.K10TEST.LOAD.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
```

And create a delimited file that looks like this (with no blank lines in between):

```
CAP61-LOADED; 299

CAP61-NOT-LOADED; 0

CAP63-LOADED; 232

CAP63-NOT-LOADED; 0
```

The directory and the log file names could change, so I think I need to do some kind of search on the table prefix (CAP, CFI, etc.) to extract the 5 byte table name, then format one kind of tag if the lines contains "successfully loaded" and the other if it contains "not loaded".   I would appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q21129289.txt) DO (
  ECHO %%a|FIND /i "not loaded" >NUL
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET "loaded=") ELSE (SET "loaded=-NOT")
  FOR /f "tokens=2,3delims=:" %%c IN ("%%a") DO (
   FOR /f "delims=." %%n IN ("%%~nc") DO CALL :showresult %%n %%d
  )
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:showresult
ECHO %1%loaded%-LOADED; %2
GOTO :eof
```

This batch reads from the file `q21129289.txt` and creates a new file `newfile.txt`

Parenthesising the mainline causes the output to be redirected to the file; `>` creates anew, `>>` would append.

First, the entire line is applied to `%%a`. This is sent to `FIND` which looks for `not loaded` (the `/i` means case-insensitive)

If that string is NOT found, `errorlevel` is set to non-zero and therefore `loaded` is set to an empty string. If the string is found, `errorlevel` is set to 0 and `loaded` therefore is set to `-NOT`.

Taking `%%a` as a string, we look for the second and third tokens delimited by a colon. These are applied to `%%c` and `%%d` (the next metavariable, alphabetically) so the `full-filename minus the drive` goes to `%%c` and the entire string after the second colon to `%%d`

Next step is to pull the same trick on the name-part only of the filename in `%%c`. This neatly disposes of the path, and we want the first token given a delimiter of `.` of the rest. This is applied to `%%n`

The `CALL` then invokes the subroutine, providing the required first-part-of-the-name and remainder-of-the-line-after-the-original-second-colon` as parameters; eg

```
call :showresult CAP61  299 Rows successfully loaded.
```

The subroutine simply strings together the first parameter (CAP61), the contents of `loaded`, the string `-LOADED;` and the first string from the end-of-line chunk (299)

The output of course is redirected to the output file.

Answer (score 1):

The wonders of regular expressions :-)

The following uses [REPL.BAT - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that performs a regex search and replace on stdin and writes the result to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053). REPL.BAT should be in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere within your PATH.

```
type input.txt|repl ".*\\(.*?)\..*: *(\d*) .*? (not )?loaded.*" "$1-$3LOADED; $2"|repl "-not " "-NOT-" >output.txt
```

Comment: +1 That's clever. How does the ? make the match not greedy?  A ? matches zero or 1 of the previous term - but if the previous term is .* then I can't see how it returns a non-greedy match. Can you please explain?

Comment: @foxidrive - The [JScript regex doc link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx) embedded in the REPL.BAT script documents all the regex meta characters available to JScript, including `?` for non-greedy match. `?` has 5 different uses, depending on context.

Comment: Thanks Dave - I actually checked that documentation but in my experience it's not normal to see a character being used for multiple purposes, and in different parts of the document - so I didn't go past the first reference.  I see now where it is, so thanks.  We live and learn.

Answer (score 1):

For an exercise on splitting and string substitution

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "successfully="    
    set "not=-NOT"

    for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=:" %%a in (input.txt) do (
        for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%c in ("%%~na") do (
            for /f "tokens=1,3 delims= " %%d in ("%%b") do echo %%c!%%e!-LOADED; %%d
        )
    )
    endlocal
```

for lines as

```
c:\SSSM\logs\CAP61.K10TEST.LOAD.log:  299 Rows successfully loaded.
c:\SSSM\logs\CAP61.K10TEST.LOAD.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
```

we get

```
%%a = \SSSM\logs\CAP61.K10TEST.LOAD.log
%%b = 299 Rows successfully ... / 0 Rows not loaded ...
%%c = CAP61
%%d = 299 / 0
%%e = successfully / not
```

First `for` splits on colon to separate the file reference `%%a` from informational data `%%b`

From the file reference in `%%a`, get only the file name and split on dots to get the required part in `%%c`.

From the informational data in `%%b`, split on spaces to retrieve the row count in `%%d` and the status in `%%e`

Now that we have all the required information, the rest is formatting output. The two defined variables (`not` and `successfully`) are expanded depending of the content of `%%e` to get the correct output.

Comment: +1, I particularly like the elegance of the not/successfully translation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `awk`. download from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)

```
C:\> awk "{s=$2; gsub(/.*\\|\..*$/,\"\") ;print $0\" \"( (s>0) ?\"LOADED\":\"NOT-LOADED\" ) }" myFile.txt
CAP61 LOADED
CAP61 NOT-LOADED
CAP63 LOADED
CAP63 NOT-LOADED
```